# Returning coordinate pairs with data via json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a script that submits parameters via JS $.ajax and on my PHP page I query db and return matched data.

```
echo json_encode(array("matches" => $match));
```

It works fine, but now I need to add coordinates date as lat/lon pairs. So I am able to get this via a loop but I'm not sure how to return it back to my script.

```
$crds = array();

foreach ($data as $row) {

    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $key = $row['key'];

    $crds[$key] = $lat.'|'.$lon;
    ...
}

echo json_encode(array("coords" => $crds));
```

When the data comes back to my script I can see in response:

> {"coords":["44.76315|-101.8113","41.76313|-111.8993","40.76299|-112.8994"]}

I wasn't sure how to format it so I joined it with a pipe which is probably a bad idea.Also in my script I need to loop through it to output an array that will look something like this:

```
markerArray.push(L.marker([44.76315,-101.8113]));
markerArray.push(L.marker([41.76313,-111.8993]));
markerArray.push(L.marker([40.76299,-112.8994]));
```

Feel like I'm not making any progress and am making bad code choices... Need some help to untangle this. Thanks.

Comment: You should be just able to json_encode entire row without transforming it

Answer (score 0):

The data already looks like the correct structure, so just respond with it as-is:

`echo json_encode(array("coords" => $data));`

Then in js loop over it to add each one to markerArray (`data` being the ajax response).

`data.coords.forEach((coord) => markerArray.push(L.marker([coord.lat,coord.lon]));`